# converting unstructured data to structured data using Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I want to convert an unstructured data to structured data for easy data analysis, so i want to know if PIG or HIVE is the best. If not which other Hadoop tool can be used and how?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the most concise, yet statically typed and very flexible, is Scalding.  It's robust, concise and functional.

Scalding is an open source Twitter project that sits on top of Cascading.  Cascading sits on top of Hadoop.  What cascading does is take user defined stages, and magically 'cascade' them down into as few MapReduce phases as possible.

This page pretty much proves Scalding is the best Hadoop API:

https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Rosetta-Code

Spark (not technically a Hadoop technology, it's actually much much better) now has a magic JsonRDD - you give it a JSON file(s) and it will magically work out the scheme.

Comment: I added more detail. @user993257

Comment: Appreciate your response, but what i need is an Hadoop technology. Just an example that stores unstructured data as input and output structured data.

Comment: Yes it is a Hadoop technology. You'll have to be more specific as to what you mean by unstructured, and what you mean by structured for anyone to answer that question.

Comment: This is exactly what am trying to do, i want to relate big data to modeling and simulation so in doing that a model will take as input unstructured data e.g email, twitter messages, pictures, video etc. and in the middle the above data will have been structured and another model will take this structured data and output it.

Comment: or just any working method or technology that can structure any kind of unstructured data, i will find a way to relate it in what am doing. Thank you

Comment: Spark now has a magic JsonRDD - you give it a JSON file(s) and it will magically work out the scheme.